# How can I set html body background image using asp.net handler?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, handler

I want to set background image of html body using asp.net handler , I have the handler but I don't know how to do what I said , any helps would be appriciated .

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: There isn't really such a thin gas an ASP.NET Handler. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Are you using c# or VB.NET?

Comment: I am using c# and a .ashx handler

Comment: where do you want to set it?

Comment: can you put your `.ashx` code. You will have to call it using jQuery then only you can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean an event handler, such as the page load event handler, you can do the following.

Change your body tag to look like this:

```
<body runat="server" id="BodyTag">
```

In your codebehind, do this (C#):

```
BodyTag.Style["background-image"] = "MyImage.png";
```

or (VB.NET)

```
BodyTag.Style("background-image") = "MyImage.png"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I have a .ashx handler , but I got your idea instead of "MyImage.png" I will use my handler